# Python Packaging - Distutils for a program

Tags: python, installation, distutils

I understand distutils is the defacto standard for the module installation world, using the common

```
setup.py install
```

But what if I don't want to install my program as a module but instead as a program, that can be executed by the user?

If I'm not being clear I'm very sorry but feel free to ask more questions.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the distutils manual adequately covers this use case. I found this reference which I think is much more informative: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-package-and-distribute-python-applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd hope that you're structuring your code so that the bulk of it is modular and could be imported into other code.  In that structure than your application is a wrapper between the program's command-line and/or other user interfaces and the functionality provided by your modules.

That said, here's a pointer to the relevant documentation on [Installing Scripts](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts).

Comment: It's not so much as a script as a fully functioning PyGtk Program. I'd like to be able to for example make a .deb so it can be run like any other program.

Comment: setuptools does not help you create packages, but having a package that is installed via setuptools will greatly relieve the burden on package mantainers.  Have a look at another package that works in a similar way.

Comment: Okay. I'll go get a similar program and have a look.

Comment: @Fergus, do take a look at that "Installing Scripts" link above. This is it. If you want extra power, use `setuptools` (or better, its replacement - `distribute`). But first, try the standard library approach.

Answer (score 1):

You mean as an .exe? Use cx_freeze or py2exe.

Comment: I'm looking at for a Linux box rather than Windows.